# What is the PostgreSQL function called that allows you to reference aliased columns in SELECT statement?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, netezza, amazon-redshift-spectrum

My company is transitioning from Netezza to AWS/Redshift.  When using Netezza, it is convenient to name a column within a select statement, and then be able to reference it again, e.g.:

```
Select Column1 + Column2 as Alias1, Alias1 + Column3 as Alias2 from X where Alias1 > 0
```

Netezza allows me to do this, however I cannot within Redshift. (I also can't do this in MS SQL).  I wouldn't be able to refer to the column alias within the SELECT statement, nor would I be able to reference it in a WHERE clause.

What is the name of this functionality, and is there a way to implement it?  Without this functionality, I'm forced to tediously write sub-queries.

Thanks

Comment: are you using any type of ORM? This could easily be implemented in an ORM

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, but there is a very specific and logical reason for why not.

The phases involved in the logical processing of an SQL query are as follows *in that specific order*:

```
FROM clause
WHERE clause
GROUP BY clause
HAVING clause
SELECT clause
DISTINCT clause
ORDER BY clause
LIMIT / OFFSET clause
```

So by the time your query gets to `select`, everything else is already done. The `where` part is way before the `select` part and hence cannot see the column aliases you have set.

You can read more from this [link](https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution).

Comment: The word “can’t” is quite the overstatement. In fact you CAN on netezza. Calculated columns with a column alias can be used in where clauses, group by as well as order by, but even more surprisingly in other calculated columns further to the right in the select statement. Please do not ‘explain’ these things if you do not have knowledge about the database in question.

Comment: He was specifically asking how to do it in PostgreSQL, that's what I was answering to. The fact that Netezza (and tens of others https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_derived_databases) have extended and built on top of it is cool, but wasn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it but you can write CTEs which are similar to subqueries but arranged in logical order:

```
WITH
q1 as (
    select Column1 + Column2 as Alias1, Column3
    from x
)
select *, Alias1 + Column3 as Alias2
from q1
where Alias1>0
```